# How to get job id or job name from current running scheduled job

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

Can we get job id or job name from current running job?
For example:

```
global class MySchedule implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        Id jobId = sc.getJobId();
        String jobName = sc.getJobName();
    }
}
```

Is there any workaround to get the current job id or job name ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If you call [`getTriggerId()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_system_schedulablecontext.htm#!) on your `SchedulableContext`, it will provide the Id of your `CronTrigger`, and thence the [`CronJobDetail`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm) for this Schedulable.

From there, you can do

```
CronTrigger ct = [SELECT CronJobDetail.Name FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :myId];
```

and that'll give you the name.